# Odoo V8: Javascript widgets: How to get the settings right?

Tags: javascript, xml, widget, odoo

I'm trying to make a custom widget to change the color of a field in a form view.

I found these 2 links:

https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/can-we-apply-seperate-color-to-partilcular-column-in-tree-view-85372

https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-extend-a-view-type-e-g-instance-web-listview-extend-89487

I've based my widget on the first link. The difference in my case is that I need to do something in a form instead of a list/tree.

This is how I made it right now:

Name of my module: opcconnectie_v1_1

**/static/src/js/hewwidgets.js:**

```
 openerp.opcconnectie_v1_1 = function (instance) {
     instance.web.form.widgets.add('kleuren', 'instance.opcconnectie_v1_1.kleurenwidget');
     instance.opcconnectie_v1_1.kleurenwidget = instance.web.form.widgets.extend({
         window.alert("test if widget is called");
    });
};
```

**views.xml:**

```
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="assets_backend" name="opcconnectie_v1_1 assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
  <xpath expr="." position="inside">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/opcconnectie_v1_1/static/src/js/hewwidgets.js"></script>
  </xpath>
</template>

<record id="product_template_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.stock.property.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_template_property_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@string='Inventory']/group" position="before">
            <group>
                <field name="stocktag_status" widget="kleuren"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>                        
    </field>  
</record>    
</data>
</openerp>
```

**openerp.py**

```
'depends': ['base', 'web', 'product'],
'js': ['static/src/js/hewwidgets.js'],
```

In hewwidgets.js, I've tried to get all the "settings" correct. I'm not sure if they are correct, I don't think so. I've put a window.alert there to see if it does anything.
Later the code needs to be changed to adjust field colors.

The window.alert didn't show, so I'm wondering what's wrong with this.

Anyone who knows how to get the "settings" right?

Is there something wrong with how I "include" the widget in my project?